# Syntax error unexpected ',' when creating a hash

Tags: ruby

I have a syntax error in this line:

```
credit_card = {
  :user => :credit_card_number,
  "credit_card_date(2i)",
  "credit_card_date(1i)",
  :credit_card_name,
  :credit_card_surname,
  :credit_card_ccv
}}
```

Using 1.8.7-p370 I get this error:

> syntax error unexpected ','

Nonetheless, my app works properly but I can not fix this error. What am I missing? How can I fix this error?

Comment: The problem is that you only give one key. You need to have a key for each.

Answer (score 3):

You should do smth like this:

```
credit_card = {:user => {:credit_card=>'Your credit card info'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The hash you're trying to make is quite badly formed, you're either missing keys, or you've got the structure you want (nested?) muddled up somehow.

Can you illustrate what end result you want?

If it's just a flat hash, it needs to be more like this:

```
credit_card = {   
  :user => :credit_card_number,
  :missing_hash_key => "credit_card_date(2i)",
  :missing_hash_key_2 => "credit_card_date(1i)",
  :missing_hash_key_3 => :credit_card_name,
  :missing_hash_key_4 => :credit_card_surname,
  :missing_hash_key_5 => :credit_card_ccv } # you also had an extra end bracket here '}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Error you are getting because your Hash syntax is wrong and you wrote one more extra ending curly brace which has not its corresponding opening brace . Hash always should have key and value pair. So you can write like this.

```
user = {:credit_card => { :credit_card_number => "some_numb", 
        :credit_card_date_2i => "some_string"}, ...}
```